# Howto select an option from a dropdown menu with partial text from a database with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I currently have a DB that is entered into a website. The website recently changed a bit and now the database no longer matches the drop downs - they have added random dates into the options that are not included in my information.

The website element looks like this:

```
<select name="dgDSHeader$ctl02$ddlHService" id="dgDSHeader_ctl02_ddlHService" onfocus="javascript:scrollToPosition(this,0)" onchange="javascript:return SetEandA(this,dgDSHeader_ctl02_ddlHServiceType);">
    <option value="-1">Select</option>
        <option value="774703|13">Family Service Coordination - 12/14/2022-08/07/2023</option>
        <option value="774704|16">Speech Language Pathology - 01/09/2023-08/07/2023</option>
        <option value="774706|4">Family Therapy, Counseling &amp; Training - 12/14/2022-06/26/2023</option>
        <option value="774945|15">Developmental Instruction - 12/14/2022-08/07/2023</option>
        <option value="|3">Comprehensive Multidisciplinary Evaluation</option>
</select>
```

The values are not static, so I can't use selectByValue

Edited to add: The drop down menu is dynamic and changes with each search, so the index varies as well, so I can't use selectByIndex either.

Previously when the text matched I was using:

```
 service = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID,"dgDSHeader_ctl02_ddlHService"))
        service.select_by_visible_text(entry['service'])
```

The data I get from the DB looks like this:

"Speech Language Pathology" or "Occupational Therapy"

I think I can possibly do this with XPATH..but im having trouble with how to properly syntax it

Answer (score 1):

You can map the text before the date to its index in the dropdown and select the option by the index

```
text = 'Speech Language Pathology'
service = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "dgDSHeader_ctl02_ddlHService"))
values = {option.text.split('-')[0].strip(): i for i, option in enumerate(service.options)}
service.select_by_index(values[text])
```